# why am I getting stack overflow exception or a logic error every time; java

Tags: java, for-loop, stack, stack-overflow

Whenever I try this for-loop, I get a stack overflow error.The goal is to use the binomial distribution formula that I edited because it was giving me inaccurate math results. This caused the program to generate a stack overflow error. I changed it so it compiled, but I want the binomial distribution as a percentage over the total number of probability added up. I'm getting logic errors.

```
  for (int numOfSuccesses = 0; numOfSuccesses <= numOfTrials; numOfSuccesses++){
        for(int i = 0; i <= numOfTrials; i++){
           total+=probability;
        }
        probability += factorial(numOfTrials)/(factorial(numOfTrials - numOfSuccesses)*factorial(numOfSuccesses));
     System.out.println("Probability of " + numOfSuccesses + " successes is: " + probability/total);
  }
```

I'm sure that its incorrect whether I have stack overflow or not, but I want to know how this for-loop is causing stack overflow. Also, what do I do if the right formula inherently causes a stack overflow, which I think it might? Break statement?

Here's the logic error:

Enter the number of trials: 4
Enter the number of possibilities: 5
    Probability of 0 successes is: Infinity
    Probability of 1 successes is: 1.0
    Probability of 2 successes is: 0.36666666666666664
    Probability of 3 successes is: 0.17647058823529413
    Probability of 4 successes is: 0.1

I fixed the exception, but the best I can get is this line:

```
   if (n == 0){
```

in this separate factorial function:

```
   public static int factorial(int n){
         if (n == 0){
            return 1;
         }else{
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you've got a naive recursion based implementation of `factorial`.  Though, if you don't want a guess, and want a real answer, __include the exception in your post!__

Comment: This is not enough code to tell what causes the overflow.

Comment: Seeing this code, I think the problem may originate within `factorial` (which is most probably implemented recursively). Please post the whole code as well as the stack trace of the `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: John Stewart:  If you fix the problems with this post, downvotes will likely change to upvotes.

Comment: Note: Textbooks love to use the factorial function as a way to demonstrate how recursion works.  But in real life, recursion is a bad way to write it.  Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, your factorial implementation caused the stack overflow, not the loop.

I'm guessing that you wrote a recursive factorial method that is incorrect.  Perhaps the stopping condition is wrong.

I'm also guessing that you fail to realize how prone to overflow and inefficiency naive factorial implementations are.

You should look into the gamma function (natural log of gamma would be even better) and memoization.

You have a ratio of two factorials, which would be natural candidates for `ln(gamma)` implementation.  If you don't know why, here's a hint:

```
ln(A/B) = ln(A) - ln(B)
```

Comment: While this answer is most probably correct, I cannot understand why people post answers, if the question / problem is not clear...

Comment: I think the problem is clear.  The answer is correct.  I cannot understand why low rep trolls think snarky comments are more helpful than real answers.

Comment: The algorithm is too naive, even if you use `ln`.  Too much room for overflow and loss of precision.  Just because the math uses factorial, doesn't mean your *algorithm* should.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't an answer to your stack overflow question (we don't have enough information to answer that), I wanted to point out that computing factorials is not the most effective way to compute binomial coefficients.  Aside from being inefficient, you will run into integer overflows needlessly when the numbers get too large.

Taking C(11,5) as an example: Using the formula with factorials, this is

```
     11!
------------
 5! (11-5)!
```

But if you expand this, you will note that many of the factors cancel out:

```
1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 x 9 x 10 x 11
-------------------------------------------
1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6
```

And you can get rid of the 1..6 factors on each side, leaving

```
7 x 8 x 9 x 10 x 11
-------------------
1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5
```

It actually works better to write the factors in the numerator in reverse order:

```
11 x 10 x 9 x 8 x 7
-------------------
 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5
```

because you can now compute the answer with a simple loop.  Start with "1" as the product.  Then multiply by 11 and divide by 1; multiply by 10 and divide by 2; multiply by 9 and divide by 3; multiply by 8 and divide by 4; multiply by 7 and divide by 5.  (The divisions will always be even--no fractions, because you are successively computing C(11,1), C(11,2), C(11,3), etc.).  I'll leave it to you to work out the details of what the loop would look like.  (Note that this approach will work fine for computing C(n,0).  Also, for efficiency, note that C(n,m) = C(n,n-m); so you can compute either one and get the same result, and you should pick the one that makes for a shorter loop.)

This lessens the chance of integer overflow.  If you use factorials to compute `C(n,m)`, the value of n! may be too large to fit in a `long`, even when the answer will fit and the above algorithm would not run into overflow problems.  (For example, 21! is too large to fit in a `long`.  However, C(21,10) = 352716 and can be computed just using `int`s.)

**Note:** It appears that the question was changed signficantly after I started typing this in, so it might not address the latest version of the question.